# Hide mouse cursor in Atom-Shell

Tags: electron

Is it possible to hide the mouse cursor in a atom-shell app? I've tried adding to my index.html with a style tag to "cursor: none" for the body element but it dosent work. I am running atom-shell on windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="cursor: -webkit-grab;">
    // your conntents 
</body>
```

This will work as you have expected.